# How is bitmap arrays more efficient than logical arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, data-structures, bitmap

So, I am new to bitmaps. Please pardon the level of my question.
I am trying to make a decision on the type of datastructure I should be using to make pairwise comparisons on vectors.

I was told to use bitmaps instead of the representing each vector (40k in total),

```
v1 ={ 12,78,96,87,100,...}
```

I would like to know how bitmaps are going to increase the efficiency of the overall operation? 
Doesnt it make the length of each vector longer ? Thats where I am confused.
and also , if there is a good guide on using encoding formats.

I use python for implementation.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Generally bitmaps are used to deal with a large number of related booleans in a memory-compact way. Such as, if you had 16 booleans, you could use a single bitmap to encode all of their states in a single 16-bit integer.

It sounds like you want to compare more abstract vectors, in which case it doesn't sound like bitmaps get you anything.

Unless you're referring to bitmaps as in the image format, and the vectors in question are colour channels for an image? In that case, it does make sense to use a standard image format to represent images.